# php preg_math_all matches wrong string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I have this subpattern:

```
<?php                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          

    $wavs = 'aaaa="" wav="d" bbbbb="" wav="gerg" ccccc="" wav="" ddddd=""';        
    preg_match_all('#(?<=wav=").+?(?=")#', $wavs, $matches);                    
    print_r($matches);                                                          
?>
```

It results in this output:

```
php test.php 
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => d
            [1] => gerg
            [2] => " ddddd=
        )

)
```

While I expected just 2 matches:

```
php test.php 
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => d
            [1] => gerg
        )

)
```

What is the issue here? Why extra unrelated string is being captured?

**EDIT: (M42 response)**

```
preg_match_all('#(?<=wav=").*?(?=")#', $wavs, $matches);
```

still results in incorrect matches:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => d
            [1] => gerg
            [2] => 
            [3] => " ddddd=
        )

)
```

**EDIT: (Sniffer)**

OMG YES! THANK YOU SIR! EXACTLY WORKS!

```
preg_match_all('#(?<=wav=")\w+?(?=")#', $wavs, $matches);  

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => d
            [1] => gerg
        )

)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is the issue here? Why extra unrelated string is being captured?

```
 #(?<=wav=").+?(?=")#
            ^^^
         This is the reason, it matches everything including the space and the "
```

You probably wanted:

```
#(?<wav=")\w+(?=")#
```

Comment: this did it! Thnak you!

Comment: @Casimir et Hippolyte ? mark is for ungreedy matches imho. Is it ungreedy by default?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Nice observation, I forgot about it.

Comment: @Dannyboy No it is not un-greedy by default, but `\w` will not match `"` so no need to work one character at a time.

Answer (score 3):

Change the `+` modifier to `*`:

```
preg_match_all('#(?<=wav=").*?(?=")#', $wavs, $matches);   
//                        __^
```

or

```
preg_match_all('#(?<=wav=")[^"]+(?=")#', $wavs, $matches);
```

Answer (score 3):

to solve the issue you can replace `.+?` by `[^"]+`, example:

```
 preg_match_all('#(?<=wav=")[^"]+(?=")#', $wavs, $matches);
```